# How to fix js export issue with foundation-rails 6.4.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker

Similar to this issue (http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/53331-fresh-64-download-js-errors) but using zurb/foundation-rails. The app is built on Rails 5.1.1 and was throwing no errors until I upgraded to foundation-rails 6.4.1 and now no foundation js works at all and each foundation component is saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined` in the console. They are all referencing a line that says:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
  value: true
});
```

This could potentially have something to do with webpacker or babel based on my googling, but I haven't been able to see a logical next step to getting this fixed. I appreciate any guidance you can provide, thanks!

Comment: Issue reported at https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails/issues/231
Wait for fix or revert to foundation-rails 6.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Paul Dodd's comment - this is currently a bug that they are aware of. https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails/issues/231